# How to do a long-polling ajax request and stop it after the results are returned

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, form-submit, long-polling

I have a site (in django) that shows a report to users that is a result from database queries and some post processing work.

This is taking more than 30 seconds and is triggering a timeout (I can't change the timeout number, since I'm using Heroku).

The only possible solution I thought of was using a long polling approach.
Right now, I fire an ajax request upon the submit button like this:

```
var options = {
          dataType: 'json',
          url: '/report/url/',
          error: custom_error,
          success: show_report,
        };

$('#report_form').submit(function() { 
        // submit the form 
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
            // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
            return false; 
        });
```

This was working fine in my dev machine and also in production until the amount of data increased.

Now, I would like to include a long-polling approach to solve this problem.
I followed the instructions on this [link](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery), but it's not working as expected.

My code looks like this:

```
var options = {
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/report/url/',
      error: custom_error,
      success: show_report,
      complete: poll
        };

$('#report_form').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false; 
        });
function poll(){
    $.ajax({ url: "/report/long-polling/", success: show_report, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
};
```

I created an url ("/report/long-polling/") that does not return anything significant just to keep the connection opened.

This is not working. Here is what is happening:
1) after the form submit, the new $.ajax triggers requests to the server, not respecting the 30s timeout (as far as I understood from the link above it should trigger a new request every 30s, not less).
2) this is not solving the real problem
3) in my development server, where even the first code works, the requests to "/report/long-polling/" don't stop even after I get the report data to display

How can I make this work? Do I need to change things on the backend as well?